# What does Rails 4 cache by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

In my Rails 4 app, I want to cache as much content as possible. I have a cache store set in config. Do I still have to implement fragment caching "manually"?

Comment: Yes, try reading up on caching: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Thanks, Diego. I'd read the guide already, of course :). I must have gotten the wrong impression because the config option is ".perform_caching" (rather than something like, say, ".allow_caching").